# Issue with using a foreign key within one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to get Supervisor ID to reference Employee Id all in one table called the Employee Table. Once i run my script to create all tables and constraints everything executes successfully but when it gets to inserting data I get a message saying error more details on the attachment:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVFs5.png)

Here is the script for my database

```
create table department 
(
    dept_ID int not null identity(1,1),
    dept_name char(50) NOT NULL,
    manager_ID int not null,
    manager_start_date date not null,

    constraint Dept_PK primary key (dept_ID),
    constraint D_Name_AK unique (dept_name),
    --constraint manager_ID_FK foreign key(manager_ID) references employee(emp_ID) /*might not be needed*/
);

/*project table done*/
create table project 
(
    proj_ID int not null identity (100,1),
    proj_name varchar(20) not null,
    dept_ID int not null,
    proj_location varchar(20) not null,

    constraint Proj_ID_PK primary key (proj_ID),
    constraint Proj_Dep_FK foreign key (dept_ID) references department(dept_ID)
);

/*employee table done*/
create table employee 
(
    emp_ID int NOT NULL identity(1000,1),
    emp_name char(50) not null,
    emp_ssn char(11) not null,
    emp_address char(50) not null,
    salary decimal(10,2) not null,
    sex char(1) not null,
    date_of_birth date not null,
    dept_ID int not null,
    supervisor_ID int null,

    constraint emp_PK primary key(emp_ID),
    --constraint emp_Name_AK unique (emp_name),
    --constraint emp_SSN_AK unique (emp_ssn),
    constraint sup_FK foreign key(supervisor_ID) references employee(emp_ID),
    constraint empDep_FK foreign key(dept_ID) references department(dept_ID)
);

/*Department location table done*/
create table dept_location
(
    dept_ID int not null,
    location char(50) not null,

    constraint dept_location_PK primary key(dept_ID, location),
    constraint dept_FK foreign key (dept_ID) references department(dept_ID)
);

/*dependent table done*/
create table dependent
(
    dependent_ID int not null identity(5000,1),
    emp_ID int NOT NULL,
    dependent_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    dependent_sex char(1) NOT NULL,
    dependent_DOB date not null,
    dep_relation varchar(10) not null,

    constraint dep_ID_PK primary key (dependent_ID),
    constraint deb_emp_ID_FK foreign key (emp_ID) references employee(emp_ID)
);

/*work period table done*/
create table work_period
(
    emp_ID int NOT NULL,
    proj_ID int not null,
    pay_period date not null,
    weekly_work_hrs int not null,

    constraint pay_period_PK primary key (pay_period),
    constraint WP_empID_FK foreign key (emp_ID) references employee(emp_ID),
    constraint WP_projID_FK foreign key (proj_ID) references project(proj_ID)
);
```

Comment: Put the error message as `text`, or as a block quote in your question please. What have you tried to solve the error? What about the error don't you understand? What is the code you're running to get that error (as the above won't generate it)

Comment: Well, you're trying to insert a row where the given supervisor does not exist (yet). Start with inserting rows of employees who have no supervisor.

Comment: You cannot just randomly assign a value (100) to supervisor_ID. Nor does that actual value make any sense given that your identity column for that tables starts at 1000. You also have schema problems because there must be at least one employee that has no supervisor - that would be the actual supervisor to which all other employees report.

Comment: nvm the schema problem - supervisor_id is nullable, i read it as not nullable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First insert supervisor details in employee table and then reference it. Supervisor id 100 is not found in employee table. Thats why you are getting error.